# Yii2 Static Pages Not Found

Tags: php, yii2

I've created a view in views/sites/example.php

```
<?php   
use yii\helpers\Html;   
?>   
<?= Html::encode($message) ?>
```

Then in SiteController.php I have added

```
    public function actionExample($message = 'Hello')   
    {   
        return $this->render('example', ['message' => $message]);   
    }
```

In main.php, the urlManager is configured

```
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ],
```

when I try to access the page at localhost/example, I get a 404. What have I missed??

Comment: Can your page be found at url with `site/example` ?

Comment: Thanks, @SergiyT. yes,it can. How do I fix that? I should add that this is an established app which I have just started working on with zero Yii experience.....

Comment: You may add custom route. Something like `'example' => 'site/example',` in rules part of urlManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **rules** section of **urlManager** part of code there are rules for which URL is checked to determine controller, action etc.

Because your action is in SiteController it can be accessed by //localhost/site/example/ url (rule `'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>'`).

So to make your action accessible via //localhost/example/ url another rule should be added to rules section.

If you add `'example' => 'site/example',` to **rules** your action will be accessible on desired URL.

There is also a guide on https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing so you can better understand routing in yii2.